# C++ persistence library

Tags: library, c++, cross-platform

I need a persistence c++ library with the following attributes:

- Cross platform (Android/macOS/Windows)
- Read/Write in a given folder in an atomic way
- Nice to have: encryption
- Serialization is not necessary

What would you recommend?